# NumPy fancy indexing of a multidimensional array: case not covered (explicitly) by documentation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

NumPy documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) tells us that the following does not work:

```
>>> test_array[np.array([0,2,4]), np.array([0,1])]
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: shape mismatch: objects cannot be
broadcast to a single shape
```

However, if we do have to do something of the sort, what should one do? Currently, I use Python list comprehension:

```
test_array = np.array([ [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ], 
                      [ [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18] ], 
                      [ [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27] ], 
                      [ [28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36] ] ])
xs = [0, 2, 3]
ys = [0, 2]
>>> np.array([test_array[x, y] for x, y in list(itertools.product(xs, ys))])
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [19, 20, 21],
       [25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30],
       [34, 35, 36]])
```

I doubt that this is efficient though!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please show an example array and the expected result.

Comment: @wwii I have updated my question with what you requested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted doesn't work, so it is somewhat guessing, but I think this is what you are after:

```
>>> y = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)
>>> xs = [0, 2, 4]
>>> ys = [0, 1]
>>> np.array([y[xy] for xy in itertools.product(xs, ys)])
array([ 0,  1, 12, 13, 24, 25])
>>> y[np.array(xs)[:, None], ys]
array([[ 0,  1],
       [12, 13],
       [24, 25]])
>>> y[np.array(xs)[:, None], ys].ravel()
array([ 0,  1, 12, 13, 24, 25])
```

**EDIT** Your updated code can be made to work similarly, but it ain't pretty:

```
>>> test_array[np.array(xs)[:, None], ys].reshape(-1, test_array.shape[-1])
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [19, 20, 21],
       [25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30],
       [34, 35, 36]])
```

Comment: Is there a way to collapse only one axis? I would like the result array to have the shape (6, 3) (see my updated question) -- your method gives a shape (3, 2, 3) (without `ravel`). If only axis 0 and axis 1 could be "collapsed" somehow...

Comment: Since you didn't mention it, I must be missing something, but won't `ix_` work, e.g. `y[ix_(xs,ys)]`, which you can then reshape?

Comment: You are absolutely right... `np.ix_` wasn't really in my radar, but it definitely seems like the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

This kind if indexing is done using `np.ix_` in numpy.

```
import numpy as np
test_array = np.array([ [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ], 
                      [ [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18] ], 
                      [ [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27] ], 
                      [ [28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36] ] ])
xs = [0, 2, 3]
ys = [0, 2]
res = test_array[np.ix_(xs, ys)]
print res.shape
# (3, 2, 3)
```

The result is (3, 2, 3) because the lengths of xy, ys and the last dimension of your array are 3, 2, 3 respectively. If you want your result to be (6, 3) just reshape after indexing:

```
i, j, k = res.shape
res = res.reshape((i * j, k))
print res.shape
# (6, 3)
print res
# array([[ 1,  2,  3],
#        [ 7,  8,  9],
#        [19, 20, 21],
#        [25, 26, 27],
#        [28, 29, 30],
#        [34, 35, 36]])
```

Just a note for anyone who is interested, `np.ix_` is just a convenience function for the magic broadcasting used in @Jamie's answer. If you want to know how it works, take a look at his answer and do some reading on [numpy's broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Such syntax is possible.

```
tmp = y[np.array([0, 2, 4]), np.array([0, 1, 1])]
```

gives the same result as:

```
tmp = np.array([y[0, 0], y[2, 1], y[4, 1]])
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> y = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]
>>> y[np.array([0, 2, 4]), np.array([0, 1, 1])]
[ 0  7 13]
>>> np.array([y[0, 0], y[2, 1], y[4, 1]])
[ 0  7 13]
```

So, the syntax you proposed is wrong as the two index lists don't have the same shape.

Comment: This is not the same thing, this is a diagonal extraction.

Comment: Also, I am explicitly looking for the case where the two index lists *don't* have the same shape.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a generic solution but it fits the expectations of your example:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
test_array = np.array([ [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ], [ [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18] ], [ [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27] ], [ [28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36] ] ])
xs = [0, 2, 3]
ys = [0, 2]
expected =  np.array([test_array[x, y] for x, y in list(it.product(xs, ys))])

new = test_array[xs,...][:,ys, ...]
new = new.reshape(np.multiply(*new.shape[:-1]), new.shape[-1])
assert np.all(new == expected)
```